# How to Create and save a script on AWS, using Cloudformation ? trying to launch kafka - zookeeper node

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-cloudformation, apache-zookeeper

Before I begin just letting you know I ma pretty new to the whole thing of cloudformation and coding in general

I have been trying to write a cloud formation template to launch an instance with a single zookeeper node and going step by step.
So I wrote my userdata to download Kafka tar and unzip it.

now instead of using " bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon config/zookeeper.properties " to start the zookeeper,
I want to make a file named zookeeper and then write a shell script on it and make it executable
how do I do this in cloudformation ??

```
 DAEMON_PATH=/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin
 DAEMON_NAME=zookeeper
 
 PATH=$PATH:$DAEMON_PATH
 
 # See how we were called.
 case "$1" in
   start)
         # Start daemon.
         pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
         if [ -n "$pid" ]
           then
             echo "Zookeeper is already running";
         else
           echo "Starting $DAEMON_NAME";
           $DAEMON_PATH/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
         fi
         ;;
   stop)
         echo "Shutting down $DAEMON_NAME";
         $DAEMON_PATH/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
         ;;
   restart)
         $0 stop
         sleep 2
         $0 start
         ;;
   status)
         pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
         if [ -n "$pid" ]
           then
           echo "Zookeeper is Running as PID: $pid"
         else
           echo "Zookeeper is not Running"
         fi
         ;;
   *)
         echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
         exit 1
 esac
 
 exit 0
```

This is the script I am trying to write so I can start and stop zookeeper using
sudo service zookeeper start/stop

manually using the CLI I did the below and then just paste the script in zookeeper and save it.

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/zookeeper
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/zookeeper
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/zookeeper
```

Thank you, hope you guys understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **few ways** of doing this:

- Store the file in S3 and download it using AWS SDK in your `UserData`.
- Create the file directly in `UserData`
- Use [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) to define the file.
- Create [pre-baked AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) with the script and launch instance using the AMI

Below is an example of `UserData` which uses [HEREDOC](https://linuxhint.com/bash-heredoc-tutorial/) in `bash` to create such file.

```
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: |
              #!/bin/bash -ex                            
           
              cat >/etc/init.d/zookeeper << 'EOL'

              DAEMON_PATH=/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin
              DAEMON_NAME=zookeeper

              PATH=$PATH:$DAEMON_PATH

              # See how we were called.
              case "$1" in
                start)
                      # Start daemon.
                      pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
                      if [ -n "$pid" ]
                        then
                          echo "Zookeeper is already running";
                      else
                        echo "Starting $DAEMON_NAME";
                        $DAEMON_PATH/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
                      fi
                      ;;
                stop)
                      echo "Shutting down $DAEMON_NAME";
                      $DAEMON_PATH/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
                      ;;
                restart)
                      $0 stop
                      sleep 2
                      $0 start
                      ;;
                status)
                      pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
                      if [ -n "$pid" ]
                        then
                        echo "Zookeeper is Running as PID: $pid"
                      else
                        echo "Zookeeper is not Running"
                      fi
                      ;;
                *)
                      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
                      exit 1
              esac

              exit 0
              EOL

              chmod +x /etc/init.d/zookeeper
              chown root:root /etc/init.d/zookeeper
```

Please not I haven't run this code, thus I can't verify if it will work out of the box.

Comment: Will give this one a try.

Any other answers from anyone else, would also be high appreciated,  thank you

Comment: yes, i shall, although i did use your idea and passed the whole script in cfn:init under files and pasted the thing in contents and now running commands, still making the whole yaml file. 
lets hope it works.

Comment: @Panda07 No problem. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: did that, it wont count since i am fairly new to stack overflow :( and have less than 15 rep

Comment: @Panda07 To accept, have to click a "tick" button under upvote and downvote buttons